# Venn diagrams to prove laws true or false

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

So here's the exercise for my discrete math exam that I'm trying to solve:

Study with Venn diagrams the following two laws:

1. A ⊂ B ^ B ⋂ C = Ø ⇒ A ⋂ C = Ø
2. C ⊂ A ⋃ B ^ A ⋂ B ⋂ C = Ø ⇒ C ⋂ A = Ø

One of the is true, the other one isn't. Which one is true and which one is not? Motivate with a Venn diagram. For the law that isnt true, exemplify with three sets A,B and C that don't fullfill the law.

End of question. So here my solution begins:

In general, I find sets to be difficult. The De Morgans laws and all other laws are explained everywhere and I understand them, but when it comes to proving stuff myself I barely understand the problem and don't know how to think or where to begin.

Take the law 1 for instance (A ⊂ B ^ B ⋂ C = Ø ⇒ A ⋂ C = Ø). It is an implication, where the prefix (first part of the implication) says: A ⊂ B ^ B ⋂ C = Ø. Now, if this should be false, since this is an implication, then the entire law must be correct since an implication with a false prefix is always true?

Anyway, the task was to draw these laws into Venn diagrams to prove them right or wrong. Here's my attempt:

[Venn Diagram proof for law 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZtVS.png)

I'm confused. A is a subset of B and B intersection C is an empty set. So I placed the empty set where A and B are present, but also where B intersects with C, which is in the absolute middle. But now I'm stuck. This doesn't prove anything and this is probably all wrong. Which way is the correct way to draw proof 1 (and also 2) with a venn diagram and how do I prove them true or false from that?

Edit: after googleing a little, I found that A ⊂ B would look like this in a venn diagram:

[A subset of B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNAYA.png)

Why don't we draw it like that? Instead, the standard is to draw 3 circles even if a is a subset of b. But isnt that wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diagram the first premise: $A \subset B$. This means that there cannot be anything inside of $A$ that is outside of $B$. In a Venn diagram, you do this by shading the area inside of $A$ and outside of $B$ ... the shading means that that area is empty:

[image]

OK, now we add to this the second premise, which is that $B \cap C = \emptyset$. So this time, the intersection of $B$ and $C$ needs to be empty, i.e. shade that very intersection. We add this to the diagram:

[image]

This diagram represents the truth of the premises. The question is now: does this force the conclusion to be true?  Well, the conclusion states that $A \cap C = \emptyset$, and if you look at the diagram, we find that indeed the intersection of $A$ and $C$ is shaded, i.e. is empty. So yes, the conclusion has to be true given the diagram, i.e. given the truth of the premises. So, this is a valid argument.

For the second problem, again start with the first premise: $C \subset A \cup B$. This means that there cannot be anything in $C$ that is outside of both $A$ and $B$, and so we shade that area:

[image]

Now for premise 2: $A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset$. So, we shade the intersection of $A$, $B$, and $C$:

[image]

Now, we ask the question: does this diagram, representing the truth of the premises, force the conclusion to be true? The conclusion says that $A \cap C = \emptyset$. So, is the intersection of $A$ and $C$ empty? Well, it *could* be ... but there can also be something $X$ that is in the intersection of $A$ and $C$ but outside $B$:

[image]

As such, we can quickly generate a counterexample: we need to have something that is shared by $A$ and $C$, but not $B$. ... while it should still be true that there is nothing in $C$ outside of $A$ and $B$, and nothing in the intersection of all three. OK, easy:

$A = C = \{ bananas \}$

$B = \emptyset $

Comment: Thank you. I know very little about sets at this point but your explaination is spot-on, couldn't have asked for better. I accepted your answer and thank you for taking the time! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @JeanDoe Think of sets simply as bags in which you can put stuff.  $A$ could be the set of all cars, for example, and $B$ the set of all red objects.  Then all cars end up in $A$, and all red objects in $B$, and all red cars both in $A$ and in $B$.  Or: think of the Venn diagrams as big circles (drawn, say, on the plains of Oklahoma). Then all red car5s will be parked where the two circles overlap, all non-red cars inside $A$ but outside $B$, and all red non-cars inside $B$ but outside $A$.

Comment: Great explaination, thank you! Ill come back to this very post if I get confused with sets again

Answer (score 0):

When you have $B \cap C = \emptyset$, you can understand it as 'any element of $B$ is not in $C$'. Since in the first law, we have $A \subset B$, also any element of $A$ (which are elements of $B$) must not be an element of $C$. The implication is therefore correct.

A counterexample for the second one can be given by taking $C=A$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you. Two follow up questions though. In the first part of the implication: 
A ⊂ B ^ B ⋂ C = Ø, does A ⊂ B have anything to do with being = Ø or is it only B ⋂ C = Ø? And also, if you don't mind, I'd be super happy if you could prove this by using Venn Diagrams and post a picture of that here. Would 100% upvote you and accept your answer then. Your first explaination gave me a new understanding which would be fullfilled with venn diagrams.

Comment: Thinking about it a little bit more, I don't understand why it is true. Since the sets are separated into three circles, does that mean A ⊂ B is only present where A ⋂ B? I mean, there are parts of A that do not belong to be, clearly, since they are outside B (see my picture). And also, why would A ⋂ C = Ø be true only because B ⋂ C = Ø and A ⊂ B?

Comment: Even if A isn't inside B in the drawn Venn Diagrams, is the entire circle of A still a subset of B?

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that since A is a subset of B, A only exists where it intersects with B?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is how to do it with a Venn Diagram "proof"

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. But what do you mean that "the areas do not exist?". In the first picture for instance, where A ⊂ B, A only exists where A and B are present at the same spot, which is the intersection, did I interpret it right? And I'm still confused, what makes A ⊂ B ^ B ⋂ C = Ø lead to  A ⋂ C = Ø? Is it because the very middle of the three circles is Ø, and both B ⋂ C and A ⋂ C cover that area?

Comment: The red area is all the elements of $A$ that are not in $B$.  They do not exist.  I shouldn't have drawn them.  I should remove that from the picture altogether.  The pink is all the element that are in both $B$ and $C$.  They should not exist either.  The should be erased.